# Multiple usage of Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, chart.js

I got some code in JS which i use in my php script.( based on chartjs)

```
$licznik=0;
    foreach ($all as $key => $row) {
                                      $imiona[$licznik]=$row['imie'];
                                      $nazwiska[$licznik]=$row['nazwisko'];
                                      $tak[$licznik]=$row['tak'];
                                      $nie[$licznik]=$row['nie'];
                                      $licznik++;
                                    }


    $wynik.='<div>
      <canvas id="'.$team.'">
      </canvas>
      </div>
      <br><hr>';

   $wynik.='<script>

  var barChartData = {
    labels : ["'.wypiszimiona($imiona,$nazwiska,$licznik).'], //radni
    datasets : [
      { //głosy na nie
        fillColor : "#BA0606",
      strokeColor : "#FF0808",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data : ['.wypisznie($nie,$licznik).']
      },
      { //głosy na tak
        fillColor : "#23BA06",
        strokeColor : "#30F70A",
        highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data : ['.wypisztak($tak,$licznik).']
      }
    ]
  };
  window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("'.$team.'").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).StackedBar(barChartData, {
      responsive : true
    });

      };
  </script>';
```

It render only last canvas, the other one are not rendered ( but JS code is right (in source). I have no idea what's wrong. I'm not good in JS:(

Comment: Do elaborate  more on the code you've written for it to be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what little information you provide, I assume you are copying and pasting that js code with different php variables. Each time you do that, you are adding code that tells the client that

```
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("'.$team.'").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).StackedBar(barChartData, {
      responsive : true
    });
```

if you do this more than once, you are overwriting window.onload, and only the last rewrite will happen, meaning only the last canvas will be drawn to.

Comment: yeah, using plugin to chartjs developed from some another user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close (and open in some of them) the JS strings with double quotes. There are a few lines that lack them:

```
...labels : ["'.wypiszimiona($imiona,$nazwiska,$licznik).'"]...
...data : ["'.wypisznie($nie,$licznik).'"]...
...data : ["'.wypisztak($tak,$licznik).'"]...
```

I might have missed some.